# Generate increasing nested empty list structure with recursion

Tags: python, list, recursion

I've got an assignment in which I need to code a recursive function (with no loops) in Python that returns:

- `[[]]` if n is 1
- `[[],[[]]]` if n is 2
- `[[],[[]],[[],[[]]]]` if n is 3

A pseudo code or a hint would be really appreciated.

My current code which I'm working on:

```
def ezr(n,a,b):
    a.append(b)
    b= deepcopy(a)
    return ezr(n-1,a,b)

def magic_list(n):
    return ezr(n,[],[])
```

I'm stuck with the first function.

Comment: basically ive made a helper function named ezr. the main one is magic_list(n). the helper one is supposed to append empty lists but it just goes out of recursion depth and ive got idea how to fix this problem.

Comment: Recursive functions have to have a *base case*: a condition where the result can be determined without calling itself.  You have not defined such a case.

Comment: this is my first time coding using recursive code and its really confusing. what necessary changes do i have to make to make it work

Comment: Start by determining when you can tell what to return without making a recursive call.

Comment: can you give me the code?

Comment: Whose name is going on the assignment when you hand it in?

Answer (score 0):

```
def magic_list(n, a=[]):
    a.append(a.copy())

    if n - 1:
        return magic_list(n - 1, a)
    else:
        return a
```

for n = 3:

```
print(magic_list(3))
```

Output:

```
[[], [[]], [[], [[]]]]
```

for n = 2:

```
print(magic_list(2))
```

Output:

```
[[], [[]]]
```

for n = 1:

```
print(magic_list(1))
```

Output:

```
[[]]
```

Comment: See ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument). Also, `magic_list(0)` blows the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Here's pseudocode:

```
function f(n) {
  if (n <= 0) {
    return []
  }

  array = []

  for i = 0; i < n; i++ {
    array.push_back(f(i))
  }

  return array
}
```

Let's examine how this works.

- The base case is when `n <= 0`, we return the empty array/list `[]`.
- When `n == 1` we return `[[]]` because the loop runs one iteration, appending `[]` as the only element of the `array = []` list we're building on this frame. The loop call looks like `[fn(0)]`.
- When `n == 2`, we return `[[], [[]]]`. The loop call looks like `[fn(0), fn(1)]`, and we know `fn(1)` returns `[[]]`, giving `[[], [[]]]`.
- When `n == 3`, we return `[[], [[]], [[], [[]]]]`. The loop call looks like `[fn(0), fn(1), fn(2)]`, and we know that `fn(0)` expands to `[]`, `fn(1)` expands to `[[]]` and `fn(2)` expands to `[[], [[]]]`, giving `[[], [[]], [[], [[]]]]`.

See also [How to implement set-theoretic definition of natural numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69710955/how-to-implement-set-theoretic-definition-of-natural-numbers)

Answer (score -1):

Generally recursion is the thing you should follow, but you have to work yourself on exit condition and how to receive data from recursion stack.

For now I see there are two problems, your recursion is infinite (wouldn't work for any call).
Second is gathering data from your stack.

This should be enough to give you a lead to solve it on your own :)

```
from copy import deepcopy

def magic_list(n,a=[], b=[]):
    if n == 1:
        return []
    a = deepcopy(b)
    a.append(magic_list(n-1,a,b))
    return a

print(magic_list(1)) # []
print(magic_list(2)) # [[]]
print(magic_list(3)) # [[[]]]
```

If you strugle with visualization, use pythontutor.com

Visualization of execution step by step of code above:
https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=%0Afrom%20copy%20import%20deepcopy%0A%0Adef%20magic_list%28n,a%3D%5B%5D,%20b%3D%5B%5D%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20if%20n%20%3D%3D%201%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%5B%5D%0A%20%20%20%20a%20%3D%20deepcopy%28b%29%0A%20%20%20%20a.append%28magic_list%28n-1,a,b%29%29%0A%20%20%20%20return%20a%0A%0Aprint%28magic_list%281%29%29%20%23%20%5B%5D%0Aprint%28magic_list%282%29%29%20%23%20%5B%5B%5D%5D%0Aprint%28magic_list%283%29%29%20%23%20%5B%5B%5B%5D%5D%5D%0A&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false