# Recursive function to nested lists

Tags: python, recursion, nested-lists

I have tried to crate a recursive function that gets a number and returns a list of nested list according to the index. For example, for 0, the function returns an empty list `[]`. for 1, the function returns `[[], [[]]]`. for 3 the function returns `[ [] , [ [] ] , [ [] , [ [] ] ]]`, and so on.

```
def func(n):
    if n == 0:
        return []
    return [func(n-1)]
```

i have tried many different approaches for this problem. I cant figure out how to extend my output to nested list according to the task.

Comment: Very close question to [How do i make a recursive function in python which does the following? magic list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72186151/how-do-i-make-a-recursive-function-in-python-which-does-the-following-magic-lis)

Comment: @ggorlen Thanks! but I am not allowed to import copy, which make it harder to solve

Comment: Did you look at all of the answers at that link? It's not quite the same, because of your seemingly odd `n=0` expected result, but other than that, it's more or less the same, so you should be able to adapt techniques there to solve this.

Comment: Also related: [Sequence of nested lists recursive python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74777281/sequence-of-nested-lists-recursive-python)

Answer (score 1):

What I think you're looking for is something like this:

```
def f(n):
    L = []
    for i in range(n):
        L.append(f(i))
    return L
```

My confusion stems from your examples. For `n=0`, there are 0 elements and for `n=3` there are 3 elements, but there are 2 elements for `n=1`. This should work where `n` is the number of elements in the final list

Comment: I think this answer is correct and does what the asker is apparently trying to do, but just as a suggestion to the asker, I would also add memoization to it to avoid a lot of unnecessary computation (if you want, I can edit and add behind a version with memoization)

Answer (score 1):

Each list actually contains *all* the preceding lists, not just the immediately preceding list. (Based on your example for `func(3)`, your question seems to mistakenly refer to the list returned by `func(2)` as the list returned by `func(1)`.)

```
func(0) == []
func(1) == [func(0)] == [[]]
func(2) == [func(0), func(1)] == [[], [[]]]
func(3) == [func(0), func(1), func(2)] == [[] , [[]] , [[], [[]]]]
...
func(n) == [func(0), func(1), ..., func(n-1)]
```

This is basically a set-theoretic definition of the natural numbers, due to von Neumann. Zero is define to be the empty set, and the successor of each number `x` is the union of `x` and the set containing `x`:

```
0 == {}
1 == 0 | {0} == {} | {{}} == {{}}
2 == 1 | {1} == {{}} | {{{}}} == {{}, {{}}}
```

I leave it as an exercise to implement this using lists instead of sets.