# Sequence of nested lists recursive python

Tags: python, recursion

Given some number n, I want to produce a list of size n where the following example shows how the n'th element in the list should be:

- For n=0: return `[]`
- For n=1: return `[[]]`
- For n=2: return `[[],[[]]]`
- For n=3: return `[[], [[]], [[], [[]]]`

Basically it takes the precedent lists and append them into a new list.

I've tried the following:

```py
def magic_list_helper(n, lst):
    if n == 0:
        return lst
    if n == 1:
        lst.append([])
        return magic_list_helper(n-1,lst)
    if n > 1:
        magic_list_helper(n-1, lst)
        new_list = []
        new_list.append(lst[n - 2])
        lst.append(new_list)
        return lst
```

but for n=3 I get `[[], [[]], [[[]]]]`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74752498/recursive-function-to-nested-lists/74757778#74757778

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recursive function to nested lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74752498/recursive-function-to-nested-lists)

Comment: I forgot to add that I cant use for loops

Comment: See also [Generate increasing nested empty list structure with recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72186151/generate-increasing-nested-empty-list-structure-with-recursion/74756717#74756717) which is a closer spec match than [Recursive function to nested lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74752498/recursive-function-to-nested-lists) but doesn't have an upvoted answer yet.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things to notice. First, how will you set your recursion up in a way that produces said output. Well, your output is of the form `[f(0), f(1), f(2) ... f(n)]` for recursive function `f`. The following does exactly that:

```py
def magic_list_helper(n):
    return [] if n == 0 else [magic_list_helper(n-i) for i in range(1,n)]
```

If `n=0`, it returns an empty list, else, it is going to return `[f(0), f(1), f(2) ... f(n)]`, and this, will then return `[f(0), f(1), f(2) ... f(n-1)]` and so on.

Comment: Im sorry I forgot to add that I cant use for loops

Comment: Any `for` loop can be refactored to recursion or a `while` loop (not that it's a good idea in general, just to fulfill arbitrary requirements).